# custom hints in netbeans 7.2

Tags: netbeans

Is it possible to add custom PHP or JavaScript hints in Tools > Options > Editor > Hints ?

[image: http://netbeans.org/images_www/articles/71/java/editor-codereference/customizehints.png]

Comment: Shouldn't this be on Programmers.SE?

Comment: I thought so too, but then I saw a lot of netbeans questions here and a lot of algorithm-related question on programmers.se, also see http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq